# Why DotNetUpdater not found?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i opened my project from github from Visual Sudio 16.6.3 and show mesage like this 
`The referenced component 'DotNetUpdater' could not be found.`

Comment: Does updating to VS 16.6.4 fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually "dotNetUpdater" is not a component that bothered and does not affect the application so it can be removed without any problems